# Is there an easy way to add tooths to divs using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, templates

A basic div is a rectangle.  But some websites (like Facebook) have little "tooth" on the top of it, pointing to the picture or something.

It gives it a outward tooth.

Is there an easy easy easy way to do this in JQuery?

Answer (score 2):

One "easy" way would be to add an absolutely positioned piece of graphic to the `<div>`:

```
$('div.someclass').each(function() {
    var $tooth = $('<img />', {
                src: ...,
            }).css({
                top: '-8px',
                position: 'absolute'
            });
    $(this).css('position', 'relative').append($tooth);
});
```

(Untested)

If your `<div>` has a border, you could let the graphics overlap and "extend" the border to the tip of the arrow.

---

Alternatively, I've seen this achieved using only a background image with the "tooth" on the top (ugly ASCII sketch below):

```
+-^----------+
|            |
|            |
+------------+
```

Then you just need to make sure that:

1. The `<div>` has this image as background image (no-repeat, top, left),
2. The background image is *always* bigger than the `<div>` (both directions), and
3. The `<div>` has an extra top-padding (equal to the "size" of the arrow).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this what you're looking for... There's a pure CSS way to do this, which I do quite a bit. It's described [here](http://www.dinnermint.org/blog/css/creating-triangles-in-css/), among other places.

To make a tooth pointing up, add a `div` for the tooth: and then style it using a thick bottom border on a 0 pixel rectangle...

```
.tooth {
  width: 0; height: 0;
  border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px;
}
```

You'll need to position it absolutely and and adjust where it shows up.

As a jQuery plugin might look something like:

```
$.fn.addTooth = function(offset) {
    return $(this).each(function() {
      $('<div>').addClass('tooth').css({
         width: 0, height: 0,
         borderColor: 'transparent transparent black transparent',
         borderStyle: 'solid',
         borderWidth: '10px',
         position: 'absolute',
         top: -20,
         left: offset
      }).appendTo(this);
      $(this).css({position: 'relative'});
    });
  }
```

The CSS will need lots of tweaking.

Creating a hallowed out triangle is a little more difficult, as you need to two rectangles masking each other. I've done this (and more complex things, actually), but to be honest, it's probably just easier to create a graphic, and then add it and position it in a similar manner.